# getting form title

Tags: forms

I have a form created by using custom module, I can get all the fields but now how should I get the form title? below is the code to get the specific field in `.module` file.

```
$form['name'] = array(
 '#title' => 'NAME',
'#type' => 'textfield',
);
```

Comment: check $form_state['name']['#title'] ?

Comment: Forms technically don't have a title as such. Do you mean a page title above the form, or you want some text inside the form that looks like a title?

Comment: yes I have a title above my form fields not a page title

Comment: can you be more specific and elaborate by attaching some screenshots ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either create a [fieldset](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7#fieldset) and use the #title property to create a legend tag, you'll need to prefix the form element with the fieldset, e.g.

```
$form['group'] = array(
  '#title' => t('TITLE'),
  '#type' => 'fieldset',
);

$form['group']['name'] = array(
  '#title' => t('NAME'),
  '#type' => 'textfield',
);
```

Alternatively, you can use [markup](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7#markup) to include any HTML you want.

Answer (score 0):

The title of a form is not a form element - you set it depending on where the form is used - e.g. as a `'title'` set in `hook_menu` ([docs](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7)) or `'info'` in `hook_block_view` ([docs](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21block%21block.api.php/function/hook_block_info/7)).

You can use [drupal_get_title](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_get_title/7) and [drupal_set_title](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_set_title/7) to get/set it.